# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1879048224 bytes) in /home/xbt/Client/htdocs/common.php on line 20

Tags: php, string, function, memory, fatal-error

Please could someone be so kind and help me with an error I'm getting. Before I explain I looked at the similar question but unfortunately it didn't help.

Anyways I tried to increase PHP Maximum memory allocation but the error message just asked me to increase it further no matter the size.

Here is the offending function.

```
function recv_string($s)
    {
        $d = '';
        while (strlen($d) < 4)
        {
            $r = fread($s, 4 - strlen($d));
            if (!strlen($r))
                return '';
            $d .= $r;
        }
        $l = unpack('N', $d);
        $l = $l[1];
        $d = '';
        while (strlen($d) < $l)
        {
            $r = fread($s, $l - strlen($d));
            if (!strlen($r))
                return '';
            $d .= $r;
        }
        return substr($d, 1);
    }
```

If it helps the line which is throwing the error is this.

`$r = fread($s, $l - strlen($d));`

Thanks in advance.

Dan